# IOS / PASSBOOK: Download a file (.pkpass) from dynamic link from IOS webview

Tags: ios, xcode, passbook

I’m developing a simple IOS app. It’s a webview with navigation buttons that allows the user to navigate into my web.

I’m programming at Xcode 8.2.1 (Objetive C) with a universal device target.

In one of my URLs I show a dynamic link (that changes at each session) to allow the user to download a PDF file, and another dynamic link to download a PassBook (pkpass file). When the user selects the first button the pdf is correctly shown, but when the second button is selected nothing happens.

I don’t know if it’s due to a permission problems or if I have to add a section of code to solve this. I have found some posts about downloading with AFNetworking but my links are variables and the wevbiew must navigate to all the URLs of the site.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS webview components do not automatically process .pkpass files.  You will need to add code to process then yourself.

There is some boilerplate Objecive-C code here:
[Downloading PKPass in an iOS custom app from my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277120/downloading-pkpass-in-an-ios-custom-app-from-my-server)